Vilna Gaon's commentary on מחצית השקל
I read somewhere the following:

The verse says, "Each Jew was commanded to give מחצית השקל,
half-shekel, for the Mishkan to achieve atonement (Exodus 30:15).
צ stands in the center of the word מחצית, denoting צדקה. It is
surrounded on either side by the letters חי, life, and at the ends of
the word by the letters מת, death. This is an indication that by
giving charity one gets closer to life and keeps away from death” - Vilna Gaon

Does anyone know where I can find the original wording on the Vilna Gaon?

It seems to come from the sefer Mei Shlomo, who attributes it to the Gra:

שמעתי בשם הגר״א בזה דבר נחמד דהנה בתיבת מחצית השקל האות האמצעי ממחצית
הוא צדיק והוא ר״ת צדקה ואותיות ח״י סמוכים לו אות ח׳ לפני הצדיק ואות י׳
לאחר הצ׳ ואותיות מ״ת רחוקי׳ מאות הצ׳ מ״ם בתחלת התיבה ותי״ו בסוף התיבה
לומר לך דע״י צדקה יהיה קרוב לחיים ורחוק ממות וכמאמר הכתוב וצדקה חציל
ממות


Sefer פננים משלחן הגר"א, parshas כי תשא, comment 30:13 (in my edition, p. 133-34, it is second in the parsha). It is taken from sefer "מנחם ציון" by r. Avraham Shlomo Zalman Tzoref (Salomon).


